# JSON giving weird output in php

Tags: php, json

I'm learning php as well as JSON and can't figure out why I have following output:
JSON RESULT:

```
{
"Results": [
    {
        "user_id": "1"
    },
    {
        "email": "user@example.com"
    },
    {
        "first_name": "User"
    },
    {
        "last_name": "One"
    },
    {
        "password": "pass1"
    },
    {
        "creation_date": null
    },
    {
        "profile_type": "0"
    },
    {
        "user_id": "2"
    },
    {
        "email": "user2@example.com"
    },
    {
        "first_name": "User"
    },
    {
        "last_name": "Two"
    },
    {
        "password": "pass2"
    },
    {
        "creation_date": null
    },
    {
        "profile_type": "0"
    }
]
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
require_once 'config/db.php';
$sql = new db();
$conn = $sql->connect();

$query = isset($_GET['query']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['query']) : "";


if(!empty($query))
{
    $qur = mysql_query($query);
    $result = array();

    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($qur))
    {
        extract($r);
        foreach($r as $key => $value)
        {
            $result[] = array($key => $value);
        }
        $json = array("Results" => $result);
    }  
}

@mysql_close($conn);

/* Output header */
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

My question is, why does it split each value into new record, I want each MySQL record to be one JSON record.

Comment: There's nothing weird about that out that is the output you requested

Comment: can you explain what is wrong in this code please?

Comment: u r looking for arrays of element .

Comment: This isn't going to be used in production, right? Running a `mysql_query` straight from `$_GET`? That seems like bad news bears if someone wants to abuse it.

Comment: i'm just learning on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just assign your row to `$result`:

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($qur))
{
    $result[] = $r;
}
$json = array("Results" => $result);
```

Comment: up to make up the undeserved dv

Comment: What do you mean you don't understand @devofash? You downvoted me

Comment: @FrankerZ i don't think so. My answer's been downvoted. I haven't done anything to yours (not intentionally)

Comment: @devofash I downvoted your post for 2 reasons. #1 it pretty much copied mine several minutes afterward. #2, in your post the `$json` array was being assigned in the while loop, overwriting each previous loop. It just caused unneeded overhead, and should have been assigned outside of the while loop. As far as my downvote, I'm not quite sure what you found wrong with my post.

Comment: @FrankerZ Didn't copy you, had I done that I wouldn't have done what you mentioned in point 2. You got there whilst I was testing my code on local and I didn't check responses before posting. Anyways, the important thing is OP got the answer they were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's doing this because of your for loop:

```
foreach($r as $key => $value)
{
    $result[] = array($key => $value);
}
```

Maybe you should try something like json_encode on the data returned.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

EDIT:

Try something like this:

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score -3):

I wouldn't use mysql to start with, use PDO. But if you must, you don't need foreach. Below will do.

```
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qur))
    {
        $result[] = $r;

        $json = array("Results" => $result);
    }
```

Comment: if you inspire yourself from another poster's post, give credit. Also, try to get it right. The $json assignment should be  after the loop.

Comment: arti I think this is the answer you looking for see @FrankerZ's 
[Answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44068630/json-giving-weird-output-in-php/44068743#44068743)

Comment: @YvesLeBorg - Wasn't inspired by another post tbh. The other user got there whilst I was testing my code on local. But anyway. Glad the OP got an answer.